# Hibernate не правильно мапит поля

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

При сохранении вложенной сущности Hibernate вместо поля redmine_id подставляет поле id ,которое помечено @Id.

Как можно это исправить ?

parent.class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "feedback_issue_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "feedback_issue_generator",sequenceName = "feedback_issue_id_seq",allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "redmine_id")
private Integer redmineId;
@Column(name = "subject")
private String subject;
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
private FeedbackFile file;
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;
@Column(name = "last_update")
private String updatedOn;
@Column(name = "applicant_id")
private Long applicantId;
@Column(name = "create_date")
private String createDate;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
mappedBy = "issue",orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<FeedbackComment> comment;
```

child.class:

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "feedback_comment_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "feedback_comment_generator",sequenceName = "feedback_comment_id_seq",allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private FeedbackFile file;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "redmine_id",table = "feedback_comment")
    private FeedbackIssue issue;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private String createdOn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Сущность потомка должна ссылаться на родительский ключ.
То есть child должен ссылаться на ID родителя. Тут всё верно.
@JoinColumn указывает на то, как будет называться ссылающееся на родителя поле в child.

Например

```
Parent
   @OneToMany
   private List<child> childs;


Child
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="qwe_id")  //в таблице child будет столбец qwe_id в котором будет ссылка на ID родителя
  private Parent parent;
```